# Problem with operator inc dec in Bison used as prefix and posfix

Tags: c, operator-keyword, bison, prefix

I'm having some problems with operator management
increase and decrease (prefixes and postfixes)
using Flex / Bison, below is another answer :

[How to fix YACC shift/reduce conflicts from post-increment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890038/how-to-fix-yacc-shift-reduce-conflicts-from-post-increment-operator)

I have read that the best solution seems to be to declare them as %nonassoc
or in some cases use %right, I'm a little confused:

inserting these parameters I expect these results :

```
 1 + ++1 ;  // 3
 1 + 1++ ;  // 2
 1 + --1 ;  // 1
 1 + 1-- ;  // 2
```

however I receive this as an output :

```
1-3
2-3
2-3
2-3
```

I'll post the source I use :

...

```
%right  tplus tmin 
%nonassoc tINC tDEC
```

...

```
%type<integer> expr program

%%

program: expr tPV           {printf ( "1-%d\n",$$); }
    | program expr tPV      {printf ( "2-%d\n",$$); }
    ;


expr: tINTEGER               { $$ = $1; }
    | expr tPLUS expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr tMIN expr            { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | expr tMUL expr            { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expr tDIV expr            { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | expr tMOD expr            { $$ = $1 % $3; }

    | tPLUS expr  %prec tplus     { $$ =  $2; }
    | tMIN  expr  %prec tmin      { $$ = -$2; }

    | tINC expr                   { $$ = ++$2;    }
    | expr tINC                   { $$ =  $1++;   }
    | tDEC expr                   { $$ = --$2;    }
    | expr tDEC                   { $$ =  $1--;   }

    | tP0 expr tP1                { $$ =  $2; }
    ;

%%
```

can you give me some suggestions? 
Thanks in advance 
Claudio

**Solution** :

```
program: line
    | program line
    ;
line: tPV { } 
    | expr tPV { printf("\n[%d]\n", $1); }
    ;
```

the error was not in grammar, but in non-terminal !

output :

```
main.exe < prova.txt

[3]

[2]

[1]

[2]
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you think carefully about what `$$` means in `program expr tPV  {printf ( "2-%d\n",$$); }`. Even with the application of the preaction `$$ = $1;` that's not going to print the value of `expr`.

Comment: Found Error : you are right.